# Is it possible to grab the CDI container from inside a JUnit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, cdi

Using CDI, is it possible to grab the CDI container?

I was creating a unit test and wanted to access the CDI container from inside the JUnit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [CDI 1.1](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html), you can use [`CDI.current()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/CDI.html#current--). It returns the [`CDI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/CDI.html) instance that provides access to the current container.

Depending on the tests you are writting, you could consider [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/).